# Wiki-like formatting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text-formatting

I forgotten the name of this library. But it's sort of like Wiki how you type certain characters in front of your text, and then it'll make the text bold/italic/underline.

I'm not asking for the way Wiki is formatted but I'm aware there is something similar built into Rails. It's at the tip of my tongue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `textilize` view helper?  In your view, just say:

```
<%= textilize( post.body_text ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of these are implemented in Ruby:

[Comparison of lightweight markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language#Comparison_of_lightweight_markup_language_syntax)

I like Markdown, through [RDiscount](http://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/tree/master).

Answer (score 0):

RedCloth does this. It gives you textile markup (which is among the markup languages listed in Daniel's answer).

http://redcloth.org/